# Trying to use a Get_user_meta variable breaks my site

Tags: wordpress

I am having a weird problem. Anytime I try to use a variable I get from the WordPress function get_user_meta, it breaks the site. It is weird because every other variable works just fine and is coded exactly the same. Wether they are empty or not.

```
        $is_optionalcopd_completed = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'is_optionalcopd_completed' );

        $is_optionalasthma_completed = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'is_optionalasthma_completed' );
```

the bottom one works just fine, but if i even try to echo out $is_optionalcopd_completed, i just get a white screen

Any ideas what the problem may be?

Answer (score 1):

Do you get any php errors (WP_DEBUG enabled)?
Try to use `var_dump()` instead of echo, because `get_user_meta()` returns default a array.

Like the notes state: make sure the meta value exists https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta#Notes.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the user meta doesn't exists, it will not returns a blank screen, it returns an empty string.

Does your code use it after you want to echo it ?

I suggest you to verify if there is no typo error in the code.

Do you see this user meta with a var_dump(get_user_meta($user_id)); ?

That's only hints, waiting for more element to help ;-)